The "useHistory" (history.listen) method is not available in the React router dom v6
I am using React router dom v6, and the "useHistory" method is not available in the React router v6 version.
How can I implement below code with React Router com v6 version?
history.listen(onParentNavigate);
export default () => {
    const ref = useRef(null);
    const location = useLocation();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
 
    const history = useHistory();
 
    useEffect(() => {
        const { onParentNavigate } = mount(ref.current, {
            onNavigate: ({ location }: any) => {
                navigate(location.pathname);
            },
        });
 
        // HOW CAN I IMPLEMENT THIS WITH REACT ROUTER V6 VERSION
        history.listen(onParentNavigate);
 
    }, []);
 
    return (
        <div ref={ref} />
 
    )
}


Issue
React-Router-DOM 6 doesn't export any useHistory hook nor surface the history object.
Solution
Data Router
If you are using a Data Router (see Picking a Router) you can subscribe to the router.
Example:
import { createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  // ... your routes configuration
]);

import { router } from '../path/to/router';

export default () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const navigate = useNavigate();
 
  useEffect(() => {
    const { onParentNavigate } = mount(ref.current, {
      onNavigate: ({ location }: any) => {
        navigate(location.pathname);
      },
    });
 
    router.subscribe(onParentNavigate);
  }, []);
 
  return <div ref={ref} />;
};

Regular Non-Data Router
If you are not using any Data Router then you'll need to use the HistoryRouter and a custom history object.
Example:
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

export const history = createBrowserHistory({ window });

import { unstable_HistoryRouter as HistoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { history } from "../path/to/history";

ReactDOM.render(
  <HistoryRouter history={history}>
    {/* The rest of your app goes here */}
  </HistoryRouter>,
  root
);

import { history } from "../path/to/history";

export default () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const navigate = useNavigate();
 
  useEffect(() => {
    const { onParentNavigate } = mount(ref.current, {
      onNavigate: ({ location }: any) => {
        navigate(location.pathname);
      },
    });
 
    history.listen(onParentNavigate);
  }, []);
 
  return <div ref={ref} />;
};

